# Strict infinitesimals and concept of scales.

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, math-history, infinitesimals

When differential and integral calculus were first discovered, in the 1600-1700s, they were proven to be immensely useful in so many applications it is almost mind boggling. But as far as I know, it was first long into the 1900s before any strict theoretic foundation for infinitesimals was actually established.

In many modern physics and engineering applications, concepts such as **multiresolution analysis, scale spaces** and **coarse-to-fine** play an important role. Roughly speaking in those concepts short time (or length) integrals and differential operators are mixed together. Which size portion of each decides the scale / resolution.

Is there some connection between how infinitesimals were first formally defined and these developments?

Comment: Why would you imagine that either multiresolution analysis, scale spaces, or coarse-to-fine methods have anything to do with either 17th-century infinitesimals or Robinson's theory? I strongly suspect that very few if any of the people who developed those methods had any interest in the formal definition of infinitesimals (or even knew a formal definition, other than possibly having heard of it as "something some mathematicians did").

Comment: Exactly. That is why I am asking the question. If they did not look for a connection, maybe there is something to find.

Comment: Then the question is, again, why would you imagine there might be a connection?

Comment: I don't see the relevance of that question. If we never looked for answers to questions we at the time did not have all reasons clear to ask then there is lots we would never learn.

Comment: We do not learn by choosing concepts at random and looking for connections between them.

Comment: We do not learn by claiming something must be random if we don't see a pattern right away.

Comment: @mathreadler, don't pay attention to his comments. It is mere arrogant posturing.

Comment: My earlier comments are not meant to imply that the question is not worth asking; what I meant is that the question (as originally written) seems incomplete. Are we looking for the obvious connection (Robinson's infinitesimals are one way to construct calculus, and the other methods all use calculus), or is some more "special" connection sought? If the latter, what are the thoughts that led one to seek such a connection? Note that I have not voted to close the question for being unclear or lacking context; I'm merely trying to elicit clarity and context.

Comment: @DavidK, it seems clear what the OP is asking.  Infinitesimals are routinely used in applied mathematics; they were only rigorously defined by Robinson in the 1960s; have these rigorous infinitesimals been used to clarify the procedures used by applied mathematicians? You can't get much clearer than that, and the answer is affirmative as per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2655330/72694).

Comment: @MikhailKatz I grant that it's abundantly clear (as your evidence shows) that the use of infinitesimals in applied math (probably) inspired Robinson to define them formally. So other applied-math applications are intellectual "cousins" (at least) of Robinson's infinitesimals. Is that enough, or are we looking for some way that the formal definition fed back into and enhanced these other applications? I should note that my own professional work involves a fair amount of applied math and I hardly ever think about infinitesimals in that context.

Comment: As with Dirac delta functions, having a rigorous theory of infinitesimals enables better understanding of procedures only dimly understood previously, and also enables new insight.  For example, the nature of singularity formation in solutions of Burgers' equation has recently been clarified using Robinson's framework for analysis with infinitesimals; see e.g., [this 2017 publication in *Journal of Differential Equations*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jde.2017.07.034). @DavidK

Comment: @MikhailKatz Yes, that is the kind of "feedback" I was wondering about. Nice find!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If multiresolution analysis, scale spaces, or coarse-to-fine methods are branches of applied mathematics (in which I am not an expert) then there is a good chance Abraham Robinson may have had something to say about them, because Robinson was an applied mathematician and in fact published a book called *Wing Theory* in the 1950s.  In fact his book introducing infinitesimal analysis contains several applications in applied mathematics; see [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/156928/28128).